# Log4Net for MonoTouch

Tags: .net, ios, xamarin.ios, log4net, system.configuration

I'm attempting to build Log4Net for MonoTouch but the assemblies required also need to be built for MonoTouch including System.Configuration and I don't have this source.

Has anyone had any luck building Log4Net for MonoTouch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A large part of MonoTouch is built upon the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) project. This means the majority of the source code, including the [base class libraries](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class) (BCL), are available as open source on github.

Part of Mono's BCL is the [System.Configuration.dll](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System.Configuration) assembly so you can, technically, rebuild this assembly (from source) to use it inside your own projects.

The most difficult part will be to ensure that `System.Configuration` does not depend on things that are not part of the BCL profile shipped with MonoTouch (a superset of the Silverlight profile). That might require a bit of surgery to add/remove the required types and ensure you have everything required for your own project (Log4Net in this case).

Comment: Thank you.  I'm going to get the source and give it a shot but I'm guessing not only will System.Configuration have dependencies but so will log4net have other dependencies making this a nightmare and not really a worthy venture.  Apparently the latest release of iOS changed the privileges for writing to the console so I may just look into writing logs to our applications privileged space using a file output stream.

Answer (score 1):

I would checkout ServiceStack.Logging I know that works on Mono...

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Logging

Also this thread on google groups

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/dXWkiD5BIMk